# C++ linker errors with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, linker

When I'm using opencv I keep getting this error

```
    linker command failed with exit code 1 ld: library not found for -lopencv_core.2.4.6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In my main cpp I use
 `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`
And in my build settings Header Search Paths I have the paths connect to
 `/usr/local/include`
And I have these two files in my library libopencv_highgui.2.4.6.dylib and libopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib

Comment: Please post the exact error message along with some context. I believe its impossible to help without that.

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CompileOpenCVUsingLinux) on the opencv site suggests using **cv** for the main library and **highgui** rather than the names you're using.

If that doesn't work, I'd try omitting the version suffix (2.4.6) from what you're already using.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, assuming you are using xcode (which I suspect), I had the same problem, you should go to *Build Settings* and find *Library Search Paths* under *Search Paths* and set it to "/usr/local/lib". That should fix this.