# Linking OpenCV to XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

I'm following this:
http://sadeepj.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/installing-and-configuring-opencv-to.html

I had a problem, compiling. But I already fixed it, modifying 2 files...

Now I'm trying to run that example.

And I get this error message:

> Ld
>   /Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Products/Debug/DemoOpenCV2
>   normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/eduardoreis/Documents/XCodeDevelopment/DemoOpenCV2
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
>   -L/Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Products/Debug
>   -F/Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Products/Debug
>   -filelist /Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Intermediates/DemoOpenCV2.build/Debug/DemoOpenCV2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DemoOpenCV2.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -stdlib=libc++ -lopencv_core.2.4.6 -lopencv_highgui.2.4.6 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Intermediates/DemoOpenCV2.build/Debug/DemoOpenCV2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DemoOpenCV2_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Products/Debug/DemoOpenCV2
>
> ld: library not found for -lopencv_core.2.4.6 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I follows all steps already. And I can't even build it.
Please, help me.

[Before someone says that it is a duplicated post, I know it, here is the original one:
[C++ linker errors with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663548/c-linker-errors-with-opencv).
I'm sorry. But I can't even comment on that one :/ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, Finally solved:

Some considerations:

- Realize that even it is looking for -l **opencv_core.2.4.6**, the
  compiler will get the right file, if it is added correctly with other
  name, in this case **libopencv_core.2.4.dylib**
- I was adding the files with **Project>Add files to...** and then creating a group and dragging the files into the group. This was messing up the linkings in **Project>Link Binary with Libraries**. So I had to do it again by dragging the files in the group into that spot.

After theses things I had the situation where I had the two files (core and highgui) and 4 errors:

> Ld
>   /Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Products/Debug/DemoOpenCV2
>   normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/eduardoreis/Documents/XCodeDevelopment/DemoOpenCV2
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
>   -L/Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Products/Debug
>   -L/Users/eduardoreis/Downloads/opencv-2.4.6.1/build/lib/Debug -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4 -L/usr/local/lib/wine -L/usr/local/Cellar/wine/1.4.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.5/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/qscintilla2/2.7.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libicns/0.8.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/jasper/1.900.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms/1.19/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.14/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.3/lib -F/Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Products/Debug
>   -F/usr/local/lib -filelist /Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Intermediates/DemoOpenCV2.build/Debug/DemoOpenCV2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DemoOpenCV2.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -stdlib=libc++ -lopencv_core.2.4 -lopencv_highgui.2.4 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Intermediates/DemoOpenCV2.build/Debug/DemoOpenCV2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DemoOpenCV2_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/eduardoreis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoOpenCV2-cqudsdzwopsadacnkbwrsxuncofg/Build/Products/Debug/DemoOpenCV2
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "cv::namedWindow(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&,
>   int)", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o   "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&,
>   int)", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o   "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&,
>   cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Then (thanks God and some days of googling) I got this:

> Select your project, go to the **Build Settings tab**, filter by **c++
>   standard library**, and set this parameter to **libstdc++ (GNU C++
>   standard library).**

from: [Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error when linking OpenCV in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078512/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-error-when-linking-opencv-in-xcode)

And finally it was sunny again in my code environment...

Comment: For some reason I getting again this problem. Even changing to c++ standard library. :/

Comment: can you explain the "by dragging the files in the group into that spot."

Comment: I had mysterious (at least, to me) linking errors and that last instruction saved me:
"Select your project, go to the Build Settings tab, filter by c++ standard library, and set this parameter to libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)." Thanks!